# What is this vine (with purple flowers), and can I transplant/spread it?

Tags: identification, flowering, vines

Can anyone help identify this climbing vine with purple flowers in our backyard? It was there when we moved in, and started blooming when it got nice out (and we gave it a little water).

Someone said it might be a Rose of Sharon, but I looked at some pictures and I'm not convinced.

We love the look of it, and would like to get a matching one for the other side of the trellis, or maybe get a cutting to grow it elsewhere too. Is this a good idea?

[image: Vine with flowers]

Here is a close-up shot of a flower:

[image: Flower close-up]

Comment: Could you post a close-up of the leaves and flowers? I think it's a Clematis of some type but a better photo would help identification.

Comment: @NiallC. I added a close-up. Unfortunately we have had a heat wave and a lot of the flowers are gone or shriveled, but hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a [clematis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clematis), a climbing vine with hundreds of cultivars. I originally thought it was a Jackmannii cultivar but the colour is not quite right. To confirm the identification look for tendrils that come off the vine and help it cling and older stems that are thin but woody.

Propagation of the species is easy from seed, the cultivars may not be so vigorous. Cuttings [can be taken](http://apps.rhs.org.uk/advicesearch/profile.aspx?pid=97) and [various methods](http://www.britishclematis.org.uk/Cutting.htm) are successful. To go from a cutting or seed to flowering plant can take three years or more.

They do not transplant or divide well but most cultivars are available for about $10 to $20 dollars at your local nursery.